# How to get the values of default checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox

I was working on a project of multiple checkbox. There, I want the checkboxes to be checked from the start and the value to be in the form(I am using reactive form). The user can unselect the boxes according to their wish and the data will be stored accordingly. This is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p8ky1e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) of the project. There I was able to make the checkbox checked from the beginning, but when I hit the submit button there is no data when I console-logged. I think this is some binding issue,but I couldn't figure out what is exactly the problem.
Can someone help?
Thanks in advance.

This is code:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="website">Website:</label>
    <div *ngFor="let web of websiteList">
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          [value]="web.id"
          (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)"
          [checked]="web.isSelected"
        />
        {{ web.name }}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
  form: FormGroup;
  websiteList: any = [
    { id: 1, name: 'HDTuto.com', isSelected: true },

    { id: 2, name: 'HDTuto.com', isSelected: true },

    { id: 3, name: 'NiceSnippets.com', isSelected: true },
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      website: this.fb.array([], [Validators.required]),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
  onCheckboxChange(e: any) {
    const website: FormArray = this.form.get('website') as FormArray;
    console.log('checking ->', e);

     if (e.target.checked) {
      website.push(new FormControl(e.target.value));
      console.log('website ->', website);
    } else {
      //console.log(e);
      const index = website.controls.findIndex((x) => {
        console.log('x.value ->', x.value);
        console.log('target.value ->', e.target.value);
        x.value === e.target.value;
      });

      website.removeAt(index);
    }
  }
  submit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qar4ph?file=src/app/app.component.ts
Pay attention to changes in template:

1. Added `formArrayName` attribute to checkboxes wrapper and `formControlName` attribute to input element.
2. Removed `change` and `checked` attributes

In the component ts file:

1. Added initial form array values
2. Added mapping to submit method
3. Removed onCheckboxChange method

Comment: In this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b5ozjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) I tried to `console.log('this list', this.list);` and it is returning `this list
[undefined, undefined, undefined]` why is that so? Also, how do I send other data along with the checkbox data to API.(in this case, `console.log`)

Comment: Since you added a block statement in the map function with the `console.log` you need to also add `return` statement to return the mapped value.

Comment: I want to make one change [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ppied5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), when none of the checkboxes are selected I want to send a null. The `null`  right now, only sends an empty array. And if I put  'null'  instead, in console log it shows three 'null' in an array but I want only one as a string.